# How our brain discharge old CSF?

Tags: eye, brain, glaucoma, csf-cerebrospinal-fluid

Our brain produces new CSF fluid every hour, so old CSF discharge from our body.

My question is where is CSF discharge point? or how our brain discharges Old CSF from the brain.

.

There is a complete guideline of how we eat, and how its discharge. How new blood cell create and how dead cells discharged.

But i didn't ready anywhere, How our brain discharge CSF, where is its main point?

Comment: The term you should be using is reabsorbed and not discharged. The answer is "arachnoid granulations in the superior sagittal sinus" if you had proper research attempts and been reading proper materials, you wouldnt have this question.

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Answer (score 3):

After CSF flows through ventricular space into the subarachnoidal space it is absorbed into venous stream through [Arachnoid granulations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arachnoid_granulation).

My first one-line answer =)